# Unit test that legacy code reacts to ThreadAbortException in a certain way

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, threadabortexception

I've got an existing bit of legacy code that I want to get under test. Here's a repro of the essentials:

```
public class LegacyUnit
{
    private readonly ICollaborator collaborator;

    public LegacyUnit(ICollaborator collaborator) 
    {
        this.collaborator = collaborator;
    }

    public object GetStuff(HttpContextBase context, string input)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (input == "")
            {
                context.Response.End();
            }

            collaborator.DoOtherStuff();

            return "Done!";
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException) 
        { }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, this legacy unit has some issues, but for now I'm just trying to get it under test. Specifically, I want to test that `collaborator.DoOtherStuff` is *not* called if `Response.End()` raised a `ThreadAbort`.

The problem: how do you raise such an exception?

I've read through [this question and its answers on `ThreadAbortException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1856286/419956), and understand that it's special. However, I don't see from those posts how to handle this in unit tests.

Here's my attempt:

```
[Test]
public void DoesNotCallCollaboratorOnThreadAbort()
{
    var testResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var testContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var collaboratorMock = new Mock<ICollaborator>();

    testContextMock.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(testResponseMock.Object);
    testResponseMock.Setup(x => x.End()).Throws<ThreadAbortException>(); // Compile error

    var unit = new LegacyUnit(collaboratorMock.Object);
    unit.GetStuff(testContextMock.Object, "");

    collaboratorMock.Verify(c => c.DoOtherStuff(), Times.Never);
}
```

Obviously the compiler complains: `ThreadAbortException` has no available constructor. Also, it's `sealed` (probably for good reasons), so creating a "testable" sub-class won't work.

What is the proper way to get such code under test? Is it even feasible, or is the `LegacyUnit` just too test-unfriendly?

---

Full, minimal repro (empty .NET 4.5 class library with NUnit 2.6.4 and Moq 4.5.9):

```
public interface ICollaborator
{
    void DoOtherStuff();
}

public class LegacyUnit
{
    private readonly ICollaborator collaborator;

    public LegacyUnit(ICollaborator collaborator)
    {
        this.collaborator = collaborator;
    }

    public object GetStuff(HttpContextBase context, string input)
    {
        try
        {
            if (input == "") context.Response.End();
            collaborator.DoOtherStuff();
            return "Done!";
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        { }

        return null;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class LegacyUnitTests
{
    [Test]
    public void DoesNotCallCollaboratorOnThreadAbort()
    {
        var testResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var testContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var collaboratorMock = new Mock<ICollaborator>();

        testContextMock.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(testResponseMock.Object);
        testResponseMock.Setup(x => x.End()).Throws<ThreadAbortException>(); // Compile error here

        var unit = new LegacyUnit(collaboratorMock.Object);
        unit.GetStuff(testContextMock.Object, "");

        collaboratorMock.Verify(c => c.DoOtherStuff(), Times.Never);
    }
}
```

Comment: DoOtherStuff does also not get executed, when End() throws any type of exception.

Comment: True. In my real case there's all sorts of other things going on around other types of exceptions. Had to sacrifice some completeness when making the repro as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ThreadAbortException` is raised in the target thread by calling `Abort` on it. You can create a thread to run the test and call `Abort` in your mock of `testResponseMock.End` e.g.

```
testContextMock.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(testResponseMock.Object);

var unit = new LegacyUnit(collaboratorMock.Object);
var thread = new Thread(() => unit.GetStuff(testContextMock.Object, ""));

testResponseMock.Setup(x => x.End()).Callback(() => { Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); });

thread.Start();
thread.Join();

collaboratorMock.Verify(c => c.DoOtherStuff(), Times.Never);
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work nicely. One thing: I had to replace `.Do(...)` with `.Callback(...)` for my version of Moq. Any chance you know where that discrepancy comes from?

Comment: @Jeroen - Sorry, I didn't notice the `moq` tag and thought you were using rhinomock. I've updated the answer.