# nunit3 trying to test that a thread throws the ThreadAbortException when I abort the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, nunit-3.0

**Using Nunit 3**

**Test Case:** that a thread I created and started, throws an ThreadAbortException when I abort the the thread

**Expected Result:** to pass (for test to confirm that ThreadAbortException happened)

**Result:** is failed with error

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: '  Expected:     <System.Threading.ThreadAbortException> 
But was:  null
```

**Nunit 3 test code:**

```
[SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _threadViewModel.CreateThread();
    }

[Test]
    public void TestThreadThrowsAbortedException()
    {
        try
        {
            _threadViewModel.RunThread();
            Assert.Throws<ThreadAbortException>(() => _threadViewModel.AbortThread());
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException e)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Visual Studio Output Window:** the output window is correct

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. at Multthreading.ThreadRunner.WriteY()
```

**Problem:** the nunit 3 test does not confirm for me that the exception was thrown

Answer (score 2):

The CLR will automatically re-raise the `ThreadAbortException` after your catch block (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856295/21567) for more information).

You can try to use the [`Thread.ResetAbort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your test code's catch block - be sure to read the remarks.

```
[Test]
public void TestThreadThrowsAbortedException()
{
    try
    {
        _threadViewModel.RunThread();
        Assert.Throws<ThreadAbortException>(() => _threadViewModel.AbortThread());
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException e)
    {
        Thread.ResetAbort();
    }
}
```

It works for me with my test runner. YMMV.

Comment: The thread.ResetAbort() does stop the ThreadAbortException from being rethrown but only in the actual code. In the test, the exceptions are not caught. I was however able to test the ThreadState. I'm currently updating the code and will post more info soon.